# value becoming 0 for no obvious reason

Tags: c++, variables, member

for some reason, the value `mod` i am creating is becoming 0 in `keygen` despite being correct when it is made and after keygen is run. i dont get why. can anyone tell me?

```
class RC5{
    private:
        uint64_t w, r, b;
        uint128_t mod;
        std::string mode;
        std::vector <uint64_t> S;

    public:
        RC5(std::string KEY, std::string MODE, uint64_t W = 32, uint64_t R = 12, uint64_t B = 16){
            uint128_t mod = 1;
            mod <<= W;
            mode = MODE;
            w = W;
            r = R;
            b = B;
            std::cout << mod << std::endl;         // 1 << 32
            keygen(KEY);
            std::cout << mod << std::endl;         // 1 << 32 
        }

        void keygen(std::string key){
            std::cout << mod << std::endl;         // 0
            // lots of commented out stuff
        }
};
```

i am sure that uint128_t is written correctly, so this doesnt seem to make sense. if necessary, uint128_t can be found [here](http://calccrypto.wikidot.com/local--files/files/uint128_t.h).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

erm, because in the ctor you are modifying a local variable called `mod` which shadows your class member.

Comment: @calccrypto, don't beat yourself up about it. we've all done this at some point or other.. ;)

Comment: @calccrypto, on a side note, if you had a naming convention which you stuck to then it may make problems like this easy to spot. Some people often add a `_` on either side of the class member, so that when you look at the code you know whether it's a local variable or member.

Answer (score 3):

This part of RC5

```
uint128_t mod = 1;
mod <<= W;
```

creates a new local variable `mod` that hides the class member. In `keygen` you use the other `mod`.